# intranet with local databases

Tags: php, django, vpn, remote-server, intranet

Need to create a intranet for a management.
there are 4 institutions under this management:3colleges and a school

student biodata(recorded at priliminary admission until he/she leaves the school) 
and the daily financial incomes(tution fee, bus fee, co-curricular fee) , 
and expenses should be fed into the intranet.
teachers attendance is also to be tracked via a biometric(finngerprint) scanner,
which is also to be fed to the system.

the 4 educational institutions are not in the same location.
we also have the main manager's office in a 5th location.

the manager should be able to view the daily transactions and 
expenses at each institutions from his office.

even if internet is not available at any of the 4 institutions, 
data entry should be possiblle(to loacal servers i assume) and should sync data to the 
main server as soon as internet is available.

the client dosent need any type of data processing, they just need to record the data and retreive it whenever required.

questions:

1.should i use dedicated server equipment at the managers office, and have vpn connections over the internet to all institutions?

2.if no dedicated server is required at the customer premises, is online hosting via companies like godaddy is enough(so that the server is accesible by anyone with internet,via a login)?

3.is mysql(phpmyadmin)+lumen(laravel)+angular js enough for this project or should i go for python(django or tornado  with postgres or mongodb) or any other web stack?

4.should i have a desktop application ?

Comment: _"The clients also need a feature for data entry even if internet is down"_ - then they shouldn't use a web site but an application. However, if they already have the page loaded, you can use LocalStorage to store the data.

Comment: What do you mean by _"How to do this over internet in multiple remote sites"_?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson the monitoring station collects data from 4 different sites where data entry is done and stores it in its database

So i intent to connect the 4 sites and the monitoring station via internet

Comment: That was some new information. You should update your question with all the information about what you actually are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is solved,
I decided to use online hosting server for the project.
We chose php laravael phpmyadmin mysql as the web stack.
We did it completely as a web app.